# Wordpress website /lost-password/ link not working

Tags: wordpress

Whenever someone on my website tries to reset his/her password they get redirected to the following link /lost-password/. But this link does not sem to be working it takes me to the websites homepage. Any idea why this is? Im using wordpress multisites by the way.

Comment: With this little information impossible to say, please elaborate the problem and add more information. What changes have you made to the WordPress installation/theme etc? I doubt the lost password -functionality breaks all by itself.

Comment: @Esko I dont even know if it has ever worked its not my website and its possible the person before me made this change, i was hoping for any leads on where to find this certain change, i already went through my functions.php and nothing there.

Comment: Try going to WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts and making sure the lost password section has an endpoint: http://cld.wthms.co/1gn8N/2pY2wdfw

Comment: @vel Who said anything about WooCommerce?

Comment: Are you using woocomerce plugin?. @Esko is it ok?

Comment: @val Of course it's ok to ask, and you might be right, who knows. Bottomline is the OP needs to provide us with more information if he wants us to help him. He might or might not use WooCommerce, if he is he should share this information.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the help, it does seem to be something with the woocommerce plugin... somehoh @vel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this if you are using woocomerce plugin.

Try going to WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced and making sure the lost password section has an endpoint

[image]

Comment: My solution was actually to remove this. leave it empty. that fixed my problem.

Comment: The above solution of removing it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same, or similar problem. Found that it was a caching problem on the server, as shown here: https://www.anterik.com/solved-wordpress-woocommerce-reset-password-form-not-working/

I contacted my hosting provider and they set up a caching ignore rule on all URL's starting with /my-account/, which solved the issue.